# React Native: Issue with Image Loading - Images Not Displaying in FlatList

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm encountering a problem in my React Native project related to the Image component within a FlatList. The images are not displaying as expected. Here's a simplified version of my code:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { View, FlatList, Image } from 'react-native';

export default function MyComponent() {
  const data = [
    { id: '1', imageUrl: 'https://example.com/image1.jpg' },
    { id: '2', imageUrl: 'https://example.com/image2.jpg' },
    { id: '3', imageUrl: 'https://example.com/image3.jpg' },
    // ...more items
  ];

  return (
    <View>
      <FlatList
        data={data}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <View>
            <Image source={{ uri: item.imageUrl }} style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }} />
          </View>
        )}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

I've confirmed that the image URLs are valid, and when accessed directly, the images load correctly in a web browser. However, when rendered within the FlatList in my React Native app, the images are not showing up.

I've tried adjusting the dimensions, checking the network, and reviewing similar issues online, but I haven't found a solution. Can someone please provide insights or suggestions on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue? Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Nothing wrong with the code, so must be urls. Please provide an example.

Answer (score 0):

It should be something wrong with your project configuration:

Test this:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { View, FlatList, Image } from 'react-native';

export default function MyComponent() {
  const data = [
    { id: '1', imageUrl: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1505533321630-975218a5f66f?q=80&w=3348&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D' },
    { id: '2', imageUrl: 'https://plus.unsplash.com/premium_photo-1683910767532-3a25b821f7ae?q=80&w=3416&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D' },
    
  ];

  return (
    <View>
      <FlatList
        data={data}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <View>
            <Image source={{ uri: item.imageUrl }} style={{ width: 100, height: 100,marginVertical:4 }} />
          </View>
        )}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Demo - https://snack.expo.dev/@emmbyiringiro/6e8ef7

Note :  HTTP Secure (https) is required for URI on iOS by default.